# Help longtable ,landscape,footnotes

Tags: footnotes, longtable, landscape

I am having a problem with footnotes in lanscape longtable. Below the code I am using ,but the footnote are not appearing at all.Also I tried to use minipage ,but it seems that it doesn't work.
Thanks :)

```
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C}

\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\toprule 
    Study && \multicolumn{2}{C}{Flow} && \multicolumn{3}{C}{Uncertain Parameters} &&\multicolumn{5}{C}{Uncertainty Approach} &&
         Key findings\\
\cline{3-4}
\cline{6-8}
\cline{10-14}
    && Forward & Reverse 
    && Demand & Supply & Others 
        &&SP\footnote{Stochastic Programming.} & RO \footnote{Robust Optimization.}& FP\footnote{Fuzzy Programming.} & Sim & H-A
        &&\\

    \midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule 
    Study && \multicolumn{2}{C}{Flow} && \multicolumn{3}{C}{Uncertain Parameters} &&\multicolumn{5}{C}{Uncertainty Approach} &&
         Key findings\\
\cline{3-4}
\cline{6-8}
\cline{10-14}
    && Forward & Reverse 
    && Demand & Supply & Others 
        &&SP\footnote{Stochastic Programming.} & RO \footnote{Robust Optimization.}& FP\footnote{Fuzzy Programming.} & Sim & H-A
        &&\\

\endhead
\hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot
~\cite{el2010stochastic}\\
Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Do you want the footnotes to appear at the bottom of the table or at the bottom of the page, with normal footnotes?

Comment: I want footnotes to appear at the bottom of the table.I am sorry but I am beginner to LATEX,i just started using it couple of days ago :) @Bernard

Comment: What is the `C` qualifier (instead of the more usual `c`) for your longtable?

Comment: It is the normal c for the columns.Can you copy the code to you latex program and see the output.please @Bernard

Comment: OK. Be aware the TeX makes the difference between upeercase and lowercase letters. Moreover there does exist a package that defines the L, C and R qualifiers, but I can't remember which at the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that with the `threeparttablex` package — if your table really has to be split over pages, else the  `threeparttable` package is enough. Although the former is an extension of the latter, it has specific commands and environments if the table is split.

You must put your longtable inside a `ThreePartTable` environment and begin with the `TableNotes` environment, which contains the `text` of the long table footnotes. The notes are called with the `tnote` command and they are inserted with the `\insertTableNotes` which put where you please. I give the example with the notes inserted at the bottom o each page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lscape} 

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
\item[a] Stochastic Programming.
\item[b] Robust Optimization.
\item [c] Fuzzy Programming.
  \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{*{16}{c}}

\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\toprule
    Study && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Flow} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Uncertain Parameters} &&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Uncertainty Approach} &&
         Key findings\\
\cmidrule{3-4}
\cmidrule{6-8}
\cmidrule{10-14}
    && Forward & Reverse
    && Demand & Supply & Others
        &&SP\tnote{a} & RO \tnote{b}& FP\tnote{c} & Sim & H-A
        &&\\

    \midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
    Study && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Flow} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{Uncertain Parameters} &&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Uncertainty Approach} &&
         Key findings\\
\cmidrule{3-4}
\cmidrule{6-8}
\cmidrule{10-14}
    && Forward & Reverse
    && Demand & Supply & Others
        &&SP\tnote{a} & RO \tnote{b}& FP\tnote{c} & Sim & H-A
        &&\\

\endhead
\midrule
\insertTableNotes
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
%~\cite{el2010stochastic}\\
Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\%
Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study\\Study
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much ..I really appreciate it... .This is exactly the output I am looking for and It worked really well :) :)

Comment: Hello again , I have added three more column, and I want to resize the table iam using \resizebox but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I never really used \resizebox. Do you know you can fit your table into the page by:    1) changing the font size locally: if you type `\small`at the beginning of the landscape environment, everything will be in 10 pt instead of 12 pt.    2) You can change the horizontal spacing between columns (default is 2×6pt). Just type at the beginning: `\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}` for instance. With 19 columns, that makes 76 pt, ~ 26.6 mm.

Comment: Bernard I can't thank you enough..Many many thanks ..The table fits the page now after changing the columns spacing.