# Footnote in multirow & longtable doesn't print

Tags: tables, footnotes, longtable, supertabular

Why footnote is printed with `multirow` when I use `mpsupertabular` environnement and not in the `longtable`, & how may it run ? Thanks for yours solutions. Here an exemple : the note 3 isn't printed :

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara   
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tablehead{\hline}
\tabletail{\hline}
\tablecaption{mpsupertabular}
\begin{mpsupertabular}{|c|c|c|}
\multirow{2}{*}{primo\footnote{note 1}}&1&1\\*\cline{2-3}
&1&2\footnote{note 2}\\ \hline
\end{mpsupertabular}
\end{center}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
\multirow{2}{*}{secundo\footnote{note 3}}&2&1\\*\cline{2-3}
&2&2\footnote{note 4}\\\hline 
\caption{longtable}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
```

Moreover, I use functions such as `\gls{}` & other own functions which react by inserting footnotes, as well, the use of `\footnotemark` & `\footnotetext` is for me impossible.

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174292/help-longtable-landscape-footnotes

Comment: @Augustin, it not really helps, because this solution is the same logic than `\footnotemark` but in the `threeparttable` environnement. Thanks for your help. We continue our research…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `adjustbox` package for get centered tables with footnote and `minipage` option for this environment

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tablehead{\hline}
\tabletail{\hline}
\tablecaption{mpsupertabular}
\begin{mpsupertabular}{|c|c|c|}
\multirow{2}{*}{primo\footnote{note 1}}&1&1\\*\cline{2-3}
&1&2\footnote{note 2}\\ \hline
\end{mpsupertabular}
\end{center}

%\begin{table}
%\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
%\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
%\hline\endhead
%\hline\endfoot
%\multirow{2}{*}{secundo\footnote{note 3}}&2&1\\*\cline{2-3}
%&2&2\footnote{note 4}\\\hline 
%\caption{longtable}
%\end{longtable}
%\end{minipage}
%\end{table}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.5\textwidth,margin=0pt \smallskipamount,center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
\multirow{2}{*}{secundo\footnote{note 3}}&2&1\\*\cline{2-3}
&2&2\footnote{note 4}\\\hline 
\caption{longtable}
\end{longtable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the code, there are another way to obtain centered tables with footnote (commented code) without `adjustbox` package. I suggest you uncomment this code and try run separately each example ...

I see your comment, in that case you can use `footnote` package and it `savebox` environment ...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\tablehead{\hline}
\tabletail{\hline}
\tablecaption{mpsupertabular}
\begin{mpsupertabular}{|c|c|c|}
\multirow{2}{*}{primo\footnote{note 1}}&1&1\\*\cline{2-3}
&1&2\footnote{note 2}\\ \hline
\end{mpsupertabular}
\end{center}


\begin{savenotes}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\endhead
%\hline\endfoot
\multirow{2}{*}{secundo\footnote{note 3}}&2&1\\*\cline{2-3}
&2&2\footnote{note 4}\\\hline 
\caption{longtable}
\end{longtable}
\end{savenotes} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand your solution, thanks for your work. Unfortunately, I have to print my notes in the footnote space in the bottom of my pages, & not in a minipage… So your idea don't run for me. Now, I'm going to explore the `adjustbox` package ;)

Comment: Check the new code in my edited response ...

Comment: Great ! I still don't understand, but it works. I'll add that we must place the `footnote` package after some other like `xcolor` cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/incompatibility-between-the-footnote-and-xcolor-packages

Comment: In addition, it improves my footnotes from other tables ! @juanuni

Comment: Nice comment about `xcolor` and `footnote` package ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach for `longtable` footnotes which uses `mbenotes` package.

**Note:** `mbenotes` is simply a `mbenotes.sty` file and you can easily modify the commands from it as per your requirements, which I've done in my solution. Here's the MWE:
`% !TEX TS-program = arara

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mbenotes} % to print table notes!
\usepackage{alphalph} % For extended counters!

%Redefined commands from the "mbenotes.sty", as per current requirements!
\renewcommand*{\thetabnote}{\alphalph{\value{tabnote}}}
\renewcommand{\tabnotesize}{\rmfamily\upshape\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\maketabmark}{{\hbox{\textsuperscript{{\rmfamily\itshape\scriptsize\thetabmark}}}}}
\renewcommand{\tabnoteformat}{\addtolength{\baselineskip}{-1\baselineskip}\addtolength{\parskip}{0.7ex} \leavevmode\llap{\maketabmark}}
% For printing a superscript style comma between two tabnote marks!
\newcommand{\cmsp}{{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\rmfamily\itshape\scriptsize,\,!}}}}
% usage: \tabnotemark[3]\cmsp\tabnotemark[4]

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tablehead{\hline}
\tabletail{\hline}
\tablecaption{mpsupertabular}
\begin{mpsupertabular}{|c|c|c|}
\multirow{2}{}{primo\footnote{note 1}}&1&1\\cline{2-3}
&1&2\footnote{note 2}\ \hline
\end{mpsupertabular}
\end{center}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\endhead
%\hline\endfoot
\multirow{2}{}{secundo\tabnotemark[3]}&2&1\\cline{2-3}
&2&2\tabnotemark[4]\ \hline
\caption{longtable}

\tabnotetext[3]{note 3}     % save note 3
\tabnotetext[4]{note 4}     % save note 4
\end{longtable}

\vspace*{-2em}
\noindent\rule{0.4\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfil
\vspace*{-3em}

\thetabnotes[]      % prints table notes!

\end{document}
% arara: xelatex`

**Output:**

[image]

Alternatively, if you are OK with all footnotes on a page being printed at the page footer, you could use the `footnote` package and make use of its `\savenotes`-`\spewnotes` combination or the `savenotes` environment. Here's the alternative solution's MWE:
`% !TEX TS-program = arara

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnote} % to print table notes!
\begin{document}

\savenotes
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
\multirow{2}{}{secundo\footnote{note 3}}&2&1\\cline{2-3}
&2&2\footnote{note 4}\\hline 
\caption{longtable}
\end{longtable}
\spewnotes

\begin{savenotes}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\endhead
\hline\endfoot
\multirow{2}{}{secundo\footnote{note 3}}&2&1\\cline{2-3}
&2&2\footnote{note 4}\\hline 
\caption{longtable}
\end{longtable}
\end{savenotes}

\end{document}
% arara: xelatex`

Output:

[image]

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: excellent ! I like `\savenotes` & `\spewnotes` ! I'll use that. 
Your first way is interesting, for now I don't need to follow these settings, but I keep that in my mind. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Zouib you're most welcome! Just be careful with `\savenotes` & `\spewnotes` combo, as they enclose a group, so watch out! Please read the `footnote` documentation page 1 for more information. Cheers!

Comment: huh! .. and still no bounty!? ;)

Comment: Ok, I read the doc. & I understand why footnotes go now to the last page of a table. 

Sorry for the bounty ^^ : juanuni answered before you & I discover both after. It was a tough choice… I wish I could give you half each ;-)